# Ringing myself using android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am developing a small application on Google's android emulator.
I am trying to figure out how I can simulate a phone call from one instance of an emulator to another (both running on my computer). Does anyone know how this can be done?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

- Launch the dialer application on the
  first emulator. As the
  number to dial, enter the console
  port number of the second emulator you'd
  like to simulate a call on.
- You can see the port number of the instance in the windows title of the emulator.
  [alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/6c15bc13f1.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/6c15bc13f1.png)
- Press "Dial". A new inbound
  call appears in the second emulator
  instance.

Comment: There still seems to be a problem, from some reasn the emulator won't ring... Any ideas why?

Comment: I have the same problem, I also can'r ring between emulator. I just dial the port number of the second emulator ("5554").  Is that wrong ?

Answer (score 15):

Alternatively to the solution provided by `Kami`, you can use [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/guide/developing/tools/ddms.html) or just the android console (in Linux and assuming emulator port is 5554):

```
$ telnet localhost 5554 <<!
> gsm call 12345678
> !
```

Answer (score 5):

simply open the DDMS from the eclipse and choose emulator control 
and you'll find a tel bar just type the phone number you want the emulator to receive  and hit call

Answer (score 1):

In order for calling the port number to work, both emulator instances must be started from the same android AVD manager process.  Two separate 'android' processes launching different emulators will *not* be able to call each other.

Answer (score 0):

In Emulator's "Extended Controls" window, there's an option to ring the phone artificially by means of a button "Call Device". See screenshot below:

[image]