# Toggle Android emulator network traffic from emulator invocation

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm working on scripts to manage large amounts of Android emulators and I need to disable all network traffic on some of them. Because I'm doing all of this on a headless server, I cannot 
use the F8 hotkey described on the [emulater documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html#KeyMapping).

I'm currently routing the TCP traffic through a null proxy with by using `emulator-arm ... -http-proxy 0.0.0.0:0` and this blocks the traffic that I want it to.

I thought this was working well until I noticed some strange error messages while running my scripts. The console started outputting `accept too many open files` and checking the open files with `lsof` reveals numerous messages stating "can't identify protocol"

```
...
emulator- 19463 username   19u     sock                0,6       0t0 1976595845 can't identify protocol
emulator- 19463 username   20u     sock                0,6       0t0 1976595847 can't identify protocol
...
```

The only "solution" I found to this is to kill all of the emulators and then wait until this limit is reached again, which is hardly a solution at all.

Is there another way to do this while invoking the emulator? Am I incorrectly using the `-htt-proxy` switch to block the traffic?

Other people found solutions to block traffic by [manually doing this by using airplane mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499812/how-to-disable-internet-connection-in-android-emulator), but this isn't feasible for me as I'm controlling emulators via scripts. I could send keyevents to the emulator with my script and turn the phone on in airplane mode, but I would prefer something more reliable than this.

Edit: It appears that I get the "can't identify protocol" errors even when I don't route the TCP traffic through the null route, so I have no idea what's going on. Can anybody verify this null route method is the best way given my circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

Try using QEMU -net-forward argument:

```
$ANDROID_SDK/tools/emulator -avd $AVD_NAME -qemu -net-forward 0.0.0.0:0.0.0.0:80:127.0.0.1:8888
```

You will need to update `127.0.0.1:8888` to the address of your null proxy.