# Temporarily disabling internet access in android?

Tags: android, testing

I want to set up a test to see if my code works properly when there is no internet access. Is there a way to temporarily shut down internet access for a test?

I tried looking around but I couldn't find it.

Comment: You want to do it in the code? Or just disable it on your device manually?

Comment: in the code ideally, I'd like to be able to incorporate this into a JUnit test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code sample should work for android phones running gingerbread and higher: This enable/disable data connection

```
private void setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled) {
   final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager)  context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  final Class conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
  final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
  iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
  final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
  final Class iConnectivityManagerClass = Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
  final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
  setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
  setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, enabled);
}
```

Don't forget to add this line to your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Also,
I know of enabling or disabling wifi:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(status);
```

where status may be true or false as per requirement.

Also at manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: It does not work for me. I get this error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: setMobileDataEnabled [boolean]`. Device: Nexus 5x, Android version: 7.1.1

Comment: @DavidNovák: See here for further explanations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539445/the-setmobiledataenabled-method-is-no-longer-callable-as-of-android-l-and-later?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 2):

Well, to disable Wifi, you can use this code:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true); // "true" TO ENABLE || "false" TO DISABLE
```

To disable the Data connection, you could use the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4304110/450534. This method, however, does **not** work on **2.3+**

This answer here has a solution for both 2.3+ and 2.2 and below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12535246/450534. You could do a simple API check and decide which piece of code to run. Something like this should get you set up:

```
int currentAPIVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
    // RUN THE CODE FOR 2.3+
} else {
    // RUN THE CODE FOR API LEVEL BELOW 2.3
}
```

See which of the two works for you. I suspect, it would be the later. I have personally never gotten around to testing the enabling or disabling Data connectivity though.

Props to the authors of the linked solutions. ;-)

**NOTE:** *The Data Connectivity solutions are based on unofficial API's and may not work in future releases.*

Answer (score 1):

If you are using emulator, you can turn off internet access for it in `DDMS` settings.

Check out:

1. [**How to disable Internet Connection in Android Emulator?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499812/how-to-disable-internet-connection-in-android-emulator)
2. [**How to disable/enable network, switch to Wifi in Android emulator?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002886/how-to-disable-enable-network-switch-to-wifi-in-android-emulator) (Question about unit testing)