# How to detect Internet Connection State via CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I need to handle the connectivity change broadcast in my app. Every thing is great except that when it comes for the broadcast the application crashes. I am using the following code in my Broadcast :

---

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i("NET", "Broadcast started");
    Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, NewsService.class);

    boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
    if(noConnectivity) {
        context.stopService(startServiceIntent);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Connection is terminated!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("NET", "Stopped");
    }
    else {
        context.startService(startServiceIntent);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Connection is ok!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

---

This code is supposed to stop a service when no internet connection is found and to start it whenever it finds a connection.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the issue? Have you figured out where the crash is happening? Are there any messages or logs providing a clue for where the problem is?

Comment: What does the LogCat show? What is the error?

Comment: The application crashes once the internet connection is lost, it shows a dialog that the process has stopped working and it must be forced to close, in my service I used `return START_STICKY;` then `return START_NOT_STICKY;` but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lastly and after 2 days of searching I found the problem, it is about the package the broadcast is placed in [I found it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499812/how-to-disable-internet-connection-in-android-emulator?answertab=active#tab-top)