# Is it possible to simulate a specified state of internet connection ("3G", "H", ...)

Tags: android, connection, 3g

I want to test my app always in a lot of possible states of internet connection.
Is it possible to simulate a specified state of internet connection (for example "3G" or "H") 
without leaving my position?

Comment: It is possible in the emulator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002886/how-to-disable-enable-network-switch-to-wifi-in-android-emulator/3505167#3505167

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like WANEM that allows you to modify the characteristics of your internet connection, like packet loss.

http://wanem.sourceforge.net/

From your question I take it it's not exactly what you are looking for but maybe it'll give you another perspective.

Answer (score 0):

The Network Emulation Toolkit can provide this functionality.

http://blog.mrpol.nl/2010/01/14/network-emulator-toolkit/

You can set up a machine through which your traffic is routed through, and can configure the bandwidth, latency, error rate, etc. either manually or select from some built in profiles (such as GPRS).

It will also provide you the ability to monitor the current throughput and error rates.