# Android Emulator Wifi Turning On Displaying Error

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-wifi, android-wireless

[image: Now thats my Wifi in the Settings Option in the Emulator]

and once i turn it ON , this is the Issue , it gives an Error and because of that i cant fetch anything from web

[image: This is how it looks]

Any helps ? it will solve all my problem ! Thanks

Comment: Check out this:- [Controlling Emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#controlling) and [Wifi Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html). F8 is indeed the key to turn network on/off,it's work for me.

Comment: nice, never heard of Dev Tools in Android package :)

Comment: nothing working here ! Maybe its that i have changed the emulator skin thats why this stuff is all happening

Comment: Well i Found the Answer at Ubuntu IRS Channel of Android-dev . 
I just turned off my Airplane mode and now um able to fetch my entire stuff dynamically from the web !
Its working well now .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i Found the Answer at Ubuntu IRS Channel of Android-dev . I just turned off my Airplane mode and now um able to fetch my entire stuff dynamically from the web ! Its working well now

Answer (score 2):

Wifi not working on Emulator. Better to get a real device if you want to study Wifi on Android.

This article may help: [How to disable/enable network, switch to Wifi in Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002886/how-to-disable-enable-network-switch-to-wifi-in-android-emulator)

Comment: Still the error is same and i am not able to use the wifi from my emulator

Comment: As I said, Wifi doesn't work on Emulator :), use real device instead.

Comment: Well at my office , i use wifi with emulator , and it works absolutely perfect , I am coming with this problem at home and not able to figure it

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of the the date and time in our device has changed..go settings and deselect automatic and now set current system date and time...you are done