# Using qemu monitor with the android emulator

Tags: android, qemu

I m trying to get a memory dump from a Android system using the pmemsave command from qemu, but I have some problems with accessing the qemu monitor interface.

I start the emulator with the following command:

```
$./emulator -avd test -verbose -qemu -monitor telnet:127.0.0.1:1234,server,nowait
```

The emulator starts up just fine, but when I telnet to the port I am not greeted with a banner, and no input seems to have any effect. I have also tried to set *-monitor* to *stdio* without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same here. I'm afraid QEMU Monitor is no longer available.

Create AVD, telnet to it, and type `qemu monitor`:

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 5554
<snip>
qemu monitor
KO: QEMU support no longer available
```

See also:

- Tweet https://twitter.com/blundell_apps/status/536163955186860032
- Git commit https://github.com/android/platform_external_qemu/commit/aa1180ca05774398245953deb306c0e25829afee