# how to run wifi peer to peer application in android emulator..?

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi, android-wifi, android-x86

I am trying to develop an wifi peer to peer application in android(4.+).
The problem here is how to test it.

I tried to run that application in android emulator. there was no option to configure wifi in the settings menu, i also tired to enable wifi using the dev tools application form the emulator but it didn't work, And through all my googling over 3 days and i found that Android emulator is not supported the Wifi.

So i opted for androidx86 4.0eeepc using virtual box and tired to add devices both wifi and bluetooth (my app uses both bluetooth and wifi) but only bluetooth device got added and it did not work. But my virtual box detected the wifi and bluetooth devices. I just couldnt get them work with the virtual machine.

I tried everything like manually adding the addresses using terminal emulator app in androidx86 and used `netcfg` through the android commandline but neither of them worked.

Please suggest and guide me on the correct path to run these kind of applications that use wifi and bluetooth in android.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would like to know about this too. If you have an answer else where please update here for sharing. We develop using the v4.0 wifi direct api and we end up buying a few Galaxy Nexus for testing.

Comment: Have you enabled WiFi Direct in the Android settings for the two virtualbox instances? Settings --> Wireless & Networks --> More... --> Wi-Fi direct

Comment: Indeed... i also found from youtube the wifi is working fine. Not sure why / what the difference with yours.... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mngdn0Be5g4

Answer (score 7):

First, be sure you enabled WiFi Direct in the Android settings for the two virtualbox instances:

Settings --> Wireless & Networks --> More... --> Wi-Fi direct

It has been [stated as working](http://osdir.com/ml/android-platform/2011-11/msg00267.html) once that hurdle was overcome, and I'm sure many have experienced the same...just be sure to **enable wifi direct**

I would have tried exactly what you've already tried by naturally moving from the emulator to the androidx86 project. Although unreliable, I'd recommend looking at and finagling this, if you haven't yet seen it: [Android: Simulate WiFi in the emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563370/android-simulate-wifi-in-the-emulator) and [How to disable/enable network, switch to Wifi in Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002886/how-to-disable-enable-network-switch-to-wifi-in-android-emulator) most likely wouldn't have full out success but may be enough to let you know that it works or would work.

As far as testing [WiFi-Direct/WiFiP2P](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/wifip2p.html) without you yourself having a device/s, I would recommend:

- Trying out some of the fiddling as mentioned above. And read through tons of logs.
- You could always crowd source it to friends, or release an apk on a forum for a small group of testers.

Of course, both of those options are not ideal, seamless, or fast. So, I'd definitely hope you get VirtualBox VMs of AndroidX86 4.0 running as it should once you check that setting and pair up the WiFi APs :-)

Comment: hmm.... Seems you're also not in "just try to emulate Wifi in emulator" side rather than "just buy the real device" side, @TryTryAgain.

Answer (score 6):

A near future solution:

This might be something to look into in near future.
Real devices are hosted by Samsung and screens are streamed to your PC.

http://developer.samsung.com/remoteTestLab.do

According to an email responded by samsung, which I sent to them earlier.
They only have 2 devices (Galaxy Nexus) running on Android v4.0 at the moment.
Unfortunately they are not physically close to each other. (One in Korea, One in Poland)

But they are planning to upgrade existing Galaxy S2 to v4.0.
Because recently Samsung have released v4.0 upgrade for S2.
Once they done that, there will be plenty of v4.0 phones.

And you can ask them which 2 phones are physically close so you can test Wifi Direct.

**--------------------------- EDIT ---------------------------------**

There are plenty of ICS devices there now, which you can test P2P.
Check with them which 2 are physically near to each other.

Answer (score 3):

**Per the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses)**:

> Each instance of the emulator runs behind a virtual router/firewall
>   service that isolates it from your development machine's network
>   interfaces and settings and from the internet.

You have to use Network Redirection, as [described in the Developer Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#connecting). In essence, you forward specific ports using ADB. Therefore you cannot test certain things like broadcast messages.

I have tried doing what you are trying to do, and-- while I won't say it is impossible (anything is possible in computing with enough time, money, and persistence)-- I wasted a lot of time on it. You cannot treat the Android emulator as a normal network peer-to-peer device. As far as I have been able to find, it is a fork of QEMU, and that is just how the QEMU emulator is implemented.

QEMU itself *does* support [TUN/TAP bridging](http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/~djw/qemu.html), but I was never able to get it working with the Android emulator. If you want to go that route, you may want to investigate running Android in the QEMU emulator, rather than in the SDK's emulator (I see you are already trying a similar approach with VirtualBox).

Unfortunately the best way to test a peer-to-peer networking program in Android is with physical devices at this time-- unless your app can suffice with the port forwarding method.

See Also: [Issue 26:Emulated Androids should be able to communicate via TCP](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26), and [Google](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=tun/tap%20android%20emulator)

Answer (score 1):

(Repeating here [my answer elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10467406/94687).)

In theory, linux (the kernel underlying android) has [mac80211_hwsim](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/mac80211_hwsim) driver, which simulates WiFi. It can be used to set up several WiFi devices (an acces point, and another WiFi device, and so on), which would make up a WiFi network.

It's useful for testing WiFi programs under linux. Possibly, even under [user-mode linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-mode_Linux) or other isolated virtual "boxes" with linux.

In theory, this driver could be used for tests in the android systems where you don't have a real WiFi device (or don't want to use it), and also in some kind of android emulators. Perhaps, one can manage to use this driver in android-x86, or--for testing--in android-x86 run in VirtualBox.

Comment: so anyway, @imz... have you tried it also running on emulator for this wifi case?