# How to simulate process killed during phone call

Tags: android

I have found that a (generally working) game app *sometimes* crashes if a phone call comes in during the game. After much experimentation and looking at logs, I have worked out the sequence of events that cause program to crash:

1. The program is running.
2. A phone call comes in.
3. onPause() is executed.

at this point one of two things the game process may or may not be killed. This is under the control of the OS.

If it is not killed then, at the end of the phone call, onResume() is called and my program resumes perfectly without crashing.

If it is killed, then at the end of the phone call, my program will crash.

The problem I face now is that *usually* the process is not killed. So it is difficult to A) debug and B) check that any attempted fixes have worked. So my question now is, is there a way to arrange that my program *always* gets killed when a phone call comes in - or is there any other way of recreating my crash-causing scenario.

Comment: Can you deliver a stacktrace?

Comment: I don't have one on-record and the bug is refusing to occur right now :-(

Answer (score 0):

well first of all, I think that the reason for the crash is a `NullPointerException`, and you should check what happens in your `onPause` and `onResume`.

in the emulator, there is a simple way of emulating events that might happen during the general use of a device.

try reading this question: [Ringing myself using android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577785/ringing-myself-using-android-emulator)

Comment: I was chasing this bug yesterday when the OS appeared to be in the mood to crash more often. I was zooming-in on the problem when I had to finish as it was getting late. The indications were that if the process was killed then onResume was never even called. Instead it should go straight to onCreate. I wanted to double-check this today, but somehow the OS is refusing to kill my process during the call so I have no way of doing this check. Even if I could call the emulator, it would only help if the emulator always killed my game process.

Comment: I bet it was a `NullPointerException` in the onResume

Comment: Unlikely. I had a log message pretty early in onPause() which never showed up in the crashing log.